# what's the Unicode of "Share" in segoe ui symbol?

Tags: icons, share

In Windows 8.
what's the Unicode of "Share" in Segoe ui symbol  ?
example for people icon.
Any body know?

Answer (score 3):

The appropriate share glyph to use in your app is U+1f381, the wrapped present ().

The Share glyph shown in the charms bar is a protected branding element that isn't exposed through Segoe UI Symbol. If you have to use a share glyph use the wrapped present.

If you're goal is to show the Share Charm flow, you can trust that most users will find the share charm, rather than expose a share button in your app. If you are in a scenario where you are confident that the user is going to want to share, like a high score, instead of putting the share glyph in the appbar, just but a standard button that says "Share my high score" that invokes the share charm.

```
function showShareUI() {
    Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.DataTransferManager.showShareUI();
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465261.aspx

Comment: So what are we supposed to use on Windows Phone where there is no Share charm?

Comment: David, what is the guidance now for Windows 10 apps where charms are gone? Still use the "present"?